# Why can't the error in proportional control system be closed by increasing the gain?

Tags: control, feedback

Proportional control is a closed loop system in which error is fed back for reaching a particular value. However, if the error is too small, it can't make a correction.

I think that this problem will be solved when we get proper gain.
If we want to get a signal which has magnitude 10, and the error is 1,
then the real value of the signal is 9. So if we make a closed loop which has gain 1 then the signal will reach 10.

I know this is wrong but I don't know why.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Yes, you can make the static error arbitrarily small by increasing the P gain, but in real systems you'll soon have stability issues.

Comment: @ewfadsv: Please capitalise your sentences properly so you will be taken seriously. Welcome to EE.SE.

Comment: This is a great question **to anyone who understands control theory**.  The reason one cannot just crank up the gain to close the error is in no way "unclear", except to the poster, *which is why they have posted a question*.

Comment: Reducing the gain by a factor of ten should, at best, reduce the magnitude of the error by a factor of ten, so if the target is 10.0 but a P-controller reaches equilibrium at 9.0, boosting the gain b by 10x should shift the equilibrium point to 9.9, and changing the boost 100x should shift the equilibrium to 9.99.  In some cases, it may be possible to boost the gain enough to reduce the error to an acceptable level.  The difficulty is that certain effects that don't pose problems at low levels of gain become problematic at higher levels.

Answer (score 4):

Proportional control results in a stable but non zero error *when used to control a system which needs continuous input*.  The classic example of this is an oven, where P control is used to control the power to a heating element. If the power is turned off, the oven cools down. Since the power commanded by the P controller is proportional to the error, then if there is constant, non-zero power then there must also be a constant, non-zero error. A PI (or PID) controller does not have this problem.

In a system where continuous input is not required, such as positioning a servo driven by a worm drive, then in theory a P controller will eventually decay towards zero error.  In a real system, trying to build such a P controller normally results in the system oscillating or "hunting" around the target, due to imperfections in the servo, sensor or control loop. To prevent that from happening, we instead design in a deadband, which is a band near zero error which is considered "good enough". Once in that band we stop trying to reduce the error.  This deadband can be arbitrarily narrow, if you're willing to pay for arbitrarily accurate sensors etc.

Answer (score 1):

Practical proportional controllers often have an offset adjustment. That means that the error can be completely eliminated by tuning the controller for **one** operating point.

However, for any deviation from the operating point, there will be an error term that is reduced by the gain. For example, if the demand increases by 10% and there is a gain of 100, you will see a -0.1% error in the PV.

In real situations with multiple lags, you generally cannot increase the gain without bound without causing stability problems, however the proportional gain can be higher than the gain term in a PID controller because the I term tends to destabilize the system.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have a car with a DIY proportional cruise control. It's automatic so we don't have to worry about gears. Your PID is set up as follows:

- P band is 10 kph.
- You will have full throttle until you get to within 10 kph of your set speed.
- Throttle will decrease by 10% for each kph as you get nearer to your set speed.
- At set speed throttle will be at 0%.

Let's set the cruise control at 80 kph. That means we get 100% throttle up to 70 kph and 90% at 71, 80% at 72, 70% at 73, etc. up to 0% at 80 kph or above. Turn the key and let's go.

But really, you know before you start that you will never reach 80 kph. Why? Because you know that your car can't maintain 80 kph with zero throttle. You might maintain 80 kph with about 30 % throttle but you get 30% throttle at 77 kph and the car will settle down somewhere around that speed. Start climbing a hill and the speed will drop.

You can increase the gain and reduce the P band to, say, 5 kph. That will improve the error but make the car more jerky and, at some point, unstable.

To counter this we integrate the error - the *I* part of PID - and use that to automatically correct the error. In the old days of analog P controllers there was a trim point to offset the setpoint internally to compensate for the error.